# Return an array as a string JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want return an array as a string in my function.
Example:

```
return [[1],[1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,4,6,4,1]]
```

should be returned as `"[[1],[1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,4,6,4,1]]"` which is a string. I don't want to use `.join()` because it removes the `[]` brackets.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too general to the language of programming; specifically JavaScript.  Flooding SO with simple questions — that are clearly defined in the language or showcased in most  books — should be avoided.

Comment: Do you mean SO is for experienced programmers only? From Where should I get help? Please be nice.

Comment: Not at all.  There really is no dumb question, but SO should expect someone to make an effort to learn a concept via some resource / material and come here with questions when they can't grasp what it is they are learning or attempting to do.  The Q&A forum isn't intended to replace existing documentation, but more to support the learning process.

Comment: I have heard you but please look at my question and try to answer from the documentation. All they gave me was `.join()` as I have indicated above. I wish you would be helping solving problems instead of closing them simply because they aren't a problem to you.

Comment: They?  Who is they?  Where?  What are you reading?  Your question is unclear.  Even your example doesn't use variables; based on your question, you could simply return a string `return "[[1],[1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,4,6,4,1]]"`.  The question is missing information both in context into how you're arriving at the statement and in what you're attempting to do.  I've read your question.  I think it's shallow and you would do much better at reading a JavaScript book or exploring an MDN before asking a question here.

Comment: Mind you, part of my criticism here is due to your other comment *"I want to return it in a function. I don't want to use console.log"*, which suggests there's a lot you don't know if you don't understand how to adjust simple conceptual answers to meet your needs.

Comment: @vol7ron Maybe it is better to take your concern to Meta. I neither agree nor disagree completely with you. Particularly, I am not in favor of closing a question just because it is too simple. But I have also seen a lot of extremely simple questions that cannot be marked duplicate because they aren't *exact* duplicates.

Comment: @NisargShah Meta is unnecessary. When I voted to close, I chose for "other", which required a reason. The *reason* posts as a comment here. The OP had follow-up, which I addressed. I think it's run its course. It wasn't personal and I don't think he took it that way. Simple questions are discouraged for many reasons; e.g., point-farming, landing page inflation, etc. Whether SO wants to be more proactive is up to the community and admins. My vote is only one (and it'd take 5 to close) - if 4 others don't feel the same, everything is as it should be :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify` - it converts JS objects into JSON strings.

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify([[1],[1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,4,6,4,1]]));
```

Comment: I want to return it in a function. I don't want to use `console.log`

Comment: @Hoslack then return it

Comment: `JSON,stringify` is itself a function, so you won't need to wrap it inside another function.

Answer (score 1):

Return your array after JSON.stringify it. like that:

```
var arr = [[1],[1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,4,6,4,1]];
return JSON.stringify(arr);
```

It will convert the array object into string.